# Choosing a draw call when not reusing vertex data

Tags: opengl, vbo

Up until now I've always used `glDrawElements`, and have my vertex and index buffers bound. From what I've read, `glDrawElements` is generally the way to go, and it works fine. However, I'm starting a new project and am questioning whether this is still the best fit.

For the current project, I'm recomposing a 2D scene from scratch every frame. The player's character runs around, and I only draw the part of the world that is visible, generating 2D quads from the map tiles and building the vertex/index buffers.

Given that (from my understanding) `glDrawElements` works best when you upload your VBOs and make multiple draw calls against them, wouldn't it be better to use something else in this case, such as `glDrawArrays`? I've generally read that `glDrawArrays` is slower, but given that I'm having to push the vertex data every frame anyway, that might not be true here.

I don't want to switch draw calls and assume I made the right choice when I could in fact be using it improperly to begin with, invalidating any performance improvements I see.